# How do I install a nerd font for using in wsl with alacritty?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded a [nerd font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads), and installed it on windows. The font shows up under configuration pannel / fonts

[image]

I use alacritty, so added to my `alacritty.yml` :

```
font:
  family: DejaVuSansMono NF # obtained here : https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v2.1.0/DejaVuSansMono.zip
  style: Regular
```

(nb: tried different names, DejaVu, DejaVuSansMono, DejaVu Sans Mono...)

And through alacritty launch Debian wsl in it. `C:\Users\me> Debian`

But the font remains the basic consolas. I can confirm this inside debian, by launching a script like [test_fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/bin/scripts/test-fonts.sh)

Which results in

[image: this]

So how can I have a nerd font inside wsl with alacritty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the commented sample `alacritty.yml` from the latest release, it looks like you are missing a line in your config:

```
font:
  normal:
    family: DejaVuSansMono NF
```

The "normal" font needs to be specified.  The bold, italic, and bold_italic will default to the "normal" font if you don't override them.

Tested it on the Windows portable release of Alacritty using CaskaydiaCove NF using the `test-fonts.sh` you mentioned.  Not to mention the fact that my Fish/Starship prompt shows up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In more recent days the yml has been deprecated. This is how you do it with toml:

```
[font.normal]
family="DejaVuSansMono NF"
```